# Generic pair with one known class?

Tags: java, generics

I'm implementing a weighted probability algorithm, so I created a generic `Pair` class. Since the probability is calculated using numbers, the value of `Pair` would always be an `Integer`, but I wanted it to work the way where the key could be any `Object`. This is what I got:

```
class Pair<K, Integer> {
    public K k;
    public java.lang.Integer v;

    public Pair(K k, java.lang.Integer v) {
        this.k = k;
        this.v = v;
    }

    // getters and other stuff
}
```

It works fine, but I find it weird that no matter what I type instead of the `Integer` part in the first line, it works the same. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

```
class Pair<K, Integer>
```

is equivalent to

```
class Pair<K, V>
```

where the name of the second generic parameter would happen to be `Integer` instead of `V` (and thus hiding the type java.lang.Integer, which forces you to use `java.lang.Integer` instead of just `Integer` in the code, to avoid a conflict).

Your class should only have one generic parameter:

```
class Pair<K>
```

Comment: One more question, what if I want to make a, let's say, `TreeMap<K, Integer>` ?

Comment: Why would you do that? The JDK comes with a standard TreeMap class. Use it instead of reinventing it.

Answer (score 2):

You use [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) when you may accept any type.
But since you know that type to be `Integer`, you do not need to make it *generic*.

The new version with one generic type argument will look like this:

```
public class Pair<T> {
    public T t;
    public int v;
    public Pair(T t, int v) {
        this.t = t;
        this.v = v;
    }
    // ...
}
```

It is good practice, when you have just one generic type argument, to name it with the "T" letter.
Also, you can now use `int` instead of `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

The way you use it, `Integer` is just a type variable, same as `K`.

If you don't need the type of the second value of the pair to be a parameter, then don't declare it as type parameter, but just use `Integer` in the code:

```
class IntPair<K> {
    private K first;
    private Integer second;

    public Integer someIntegerSpecificFunction() {
        // do stuff to internalPair.second
    }

    K getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    Integer getSecond() {
        return second;
    }
}
```